# sql Employee database: creating activity/milestone table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

this is more of a concept question as i am still brainstorming on the right approach for this. Ive been approached by my HR department to come up with a way of tracking an employees activities as they move through the company. This could be HR related: change in name, department, job, pay, yearly evaluations, etc. It could be training related: Classes, certifications, year exams. It could be participation related: joining teams, submitting safety, quality, process improvement, etc. this list will need to be flexible.

My question is: should i be housing all of these activities in a single table (ideally with connections to other portions of the db..to pull up a yearly eval for example), or should i break them up into 'category' based tables and tie them together another way?

I'm trying to build this with flexibility in mind, as it looks that they would want to expand the use of this db to other company locations (which is a whole issue in itself).

Thanks for your insight,

Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it one table with a category column. Make it one-to-many from user.

As long as you have a company column in the user table, this new table doesn't need to know about companies.

Don't break it into different category tables unless each category will have different additional columns, and even then, you'll be getting into a complicated (polymorphic) design.

Comment: Thanks for the response. started with envisioning a table built on categories. then i thought it would be a good idea to have the opportunity for comments. then I thought it was be better design to have standardized comments based on the category chosen. This seems to be going into the polymorphic design you mentioned. Should i avoid this?

Comment: @SiTrav, you can still limit the comments based on the category without a polymorphic design. The polymorphic design isn't bad, it's just complex (adds complexity to every query). It should only be used when it absolutely fits.